# NSUndoManager continuous event

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, foundation

When i'am doing a continuous event, such as sliding on the color wheel or sliding the NSSlider, before the event i call

```
[self.undoManager beginUndoGrouping];

[sender showColorPickerWithOnChange:^(NSColor *color) {

   [[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] setBackgroundColor:self.backgroundColor];
   [self.undoManager setActionName:@"Bg. Color Change"];
   self.backgroundColor = color;

} onClose:^{

   [self.undoManager endUndoGrouping];

}];
```

This works fine, however once the undo is executed, than the setBackgroundColor is called numerous times

Is there a way to marge same undo actions into one (so that just the first undo action is executed and in the case of redo, the last action?)? smth. like

```
[self.undoManager beginMargeGrouping];
```

Comment: I think you are doing this too complicated. You only need to register one undo action before starting the slide, i.e. to set the color to the current color, i.e. the color before the slide. There is no need to keep track of the intermediate values the slider passed over. Just determine that the slider action ended when the focus left the slider or mouse up or something similar.